# Why does clicking on my Eureka service link redirect me to a login page instead of displaying ThreadPoolExecutorStatus info?

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have already register my service with Eureka,
then click the link and normally the following information should be displayed:

```
{"ThreadPoolExecutorStatus":{"BaseExecutor":{"QueueSize":0,"MaximumPoolSize":8,"CompletedTaskCount":0,"LargestPoolSize":0,"TaskCount":0,"PoolSize":0,"CorePoolSize":1,"Terminated":false,"QueueRemainingCapacity":65536}}}
```

However, my service clicked into the link towards to login page:

[image]

The backend does not intercept /actuator/info. How did this page get here?

How I close the login page?

Do not use

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the Eureka registry would not prompt this. The Spring Security API is present in the classpath, generating the default login page you see.

To ensure proper configuration, it's generally recommended to follow the order: first, configure the access rules using authorizeRequests(), and then disable CSRF protection using csrf().disable().

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Additionally, if your application has any existing security configuration, ensure the new SecurityConfig class extends the appropriate configuration class.

For example:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Override methods and customize security configuration
}
```